# Android game showing a roboter on a windmill (which is built with Minecraft-like blocks)

Tags: android, game-identification

I need to identify this Android game. I only have a screenshot of the game being played.

[image: Screenshot of the game, showing a windmill built with Minecraft-like blocks, and a small roboter]

Comment: Where did you get the screenshot from?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeM3GKS6a1c&t=83s

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This game is called: Mekorama

You can download it here: [Mekorama Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.martinmagni.mekorama&hl=en)